# li element with image and badge

Tags: html, css

I would like to create an LI element with anchor inside and image before it.
Here is the css,

```
.left-panel > ul > li > a {
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;  
        line-height:10px;
        padding:20px;
        color:#535353;
     }
```

I can't use list-style-image.

And I want to add badge in the anchor elements.

Do I need to use span? or DIV?

How can I align image and badge center in the text height?

Here is my HTML,

```
<div class="left-panel">
    <ul>
        <li class="current">
            <a href="#">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Logout</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You can try with pseudo-elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements. Also, you could put background image to a element, and set its position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use pseud-element `::before` \ `::after`

```css
.left-panel > ul > li {
  list-style: none
}
.left-panel > ul > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  line-height: 10px;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  color: #535353;
  position: relative; /*new*/
}
.left-panel > ul > li > a::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  content: " »» image «« "
}
```

```html
<div class="left-panel">
  <ul>
    <li class="current">
      <a href="#">Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Logout</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```